# How to delete n number of lines from the error log file in remote server using commands prompt

Tags: linux

I have a very large error log file( around 200 MB),in a remote server

I want to delete some last 125,000 lines from it, using command prompt

How can i do this

Comment: You want to delete the last 125000? Why do you want to delete the most recent lines?

Comment: Is not important.I just wants to know , how can i delete some few lines from the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head -n -125000 logfile
```

will get you all but the last 125000 lines from a file named `logfile`.  If there are less than 125,000 lines you will get nothing.

Perhaps you should be looking into `logrotate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the most recent 100k lines into the old log, I would do this:

```
tail -n 100000 oldlog.log > tmplog.log && rm oldlog.log && mv tmplog.log oldlog.log
```

**CAUTION:** this deletes the original log.